# forked-daapd without avahi

Tags: dbus, avahi, daap

I'm trying to setup forked-daapd, but i'd prefer it if i could run it without avahi (or rather define my own avahi service instead of using the dbus api).

The reason is that i want a netatalk share for my time machine backups and a samba share for the symbolic link support (netatalk doesn't support symlinks). Those two are defined as different services in avahi. To make that work, i have to disable avahi's dbus api, or else netatalk tends to take over all the services (osx prefers afp over smb).

If I now try to start forked-daapd, it just doesn't. Forked-daapd requires avahi's dbus api to be enabled and running. Is there some sort of way around this limitation, so that i can manually define my own daap service in avahi.

Maybe something like enabling but ignoring the dbus in avahi, or launching a duplicate avahi daemon with a different config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, eventually this was really easy. There is an option -nozeroconf in /etc/afpd.conf, which disables advertising afp shares through avahi's dbus interface. This way, I could turn avahi's dbus interface back on without afp taking over all my shares. Now I can start forked-daapd correctly.